# How can I convert normal array of objects to multilevel array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, object

My normal array object like this :

```
var b = [
    {id: 1, name: 'England',parent_id: null},
    {id: 2, name: 'Spain',parent_id: null},
    {id: 3, name: 'Chelsea',parent_id: 1},
    {id: 4, name: 'Manchester United',parent_id: 1},
    {id: 5, name: 'Real Madrid',parent_id: 2},
    {id: 6, name: 'Barcelona',parent_id: 2},
    {id: 7, name: 'Hazard',parent_id: 3},
    {id: 8, name: 'Morata',parent_id: 3},
    {id: 9, name: 'Pogba',parent_id: 4},
    {id: 10, name: 'Lukaku',parent_id: 4},
    {id: 11, name: 'Ronaldo',parent_id: 5},
    {id: 12, name: 'Bale',parent_id: 5},
    {id: 13, name: 'Messi',parent_id: 6},
    {id: 14, name: 'Suarez',parent_id: 6},
];
```

I want to convert the object array to be like this :

```
var b = [
    {
        name: 'England',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Chelsea',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Hazard'},
                    {name: 'Morata'}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Manchester United',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Pogba'},
                    {name: 'Lukaku'}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Spain',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Real Madrid',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Ronaldo'},
                    {name: 'Bale'}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Barcelona',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Messi'},
                    {name: 'Suarez'}
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

It seems it will be separated using key parent_id

But i'm still confused to implement it

How can I convert the array object like that?

Please help me guys

Answer (score 3):

1. [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `b` so it contains only items with `parent_id: null`
2. [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) remaining items, assigning children to them
3. [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) children for each of the root level parents to return them without `parent_id` field *(optional, not in the example)*

```js
var b = [
    {id: 1, name: 'England',parent_id: null},
    {id: 2, name: 'Spain',parent_id: null},
    {id: 3, name: 'Chelsea',parent_id: 1},
    {id: 4, name: 'Manchester United',parent_id: 1},
    {id: 5, name: 'Real Madrid',parent_id: 2},
    {id: 6, name: 'Barcelona',parent_id: 2},
    {id: 7, name: 'Hazard',parent_id: 3},
    {id: 8, name: 'Morata',parent_id: 3},
    {id: 9, name: 'Pogba',parent_id: 4},
    {id: 10, name: 'Lukaku',parent_id: 4},
    {id: 11, name: 'Ronaldo',parent_id: 5},
    {id: 12, name: 'Bale',parent_id: 5},
    {id: 13, name: 'Messi',parent_id: 6},
    {id: 14, name: 'Suarez',parent_id: 6},
];

const done = b.filter(person => !person.parent_id).map(person => {

  return {
    id      : person.id,
    name    : person.name,
    children: b.filter(child => child.parent_id == person.id)
  }

});

console.log(done);
```